# Storing a char array into another array - c

Tags: c

I'm wondering if anyone could help me out with the following code fragment.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to store one array in another.  I've tried everything I could think of yet all resulted in errors from the compiler.  The following is a fragment from my code that should be enough show you where I stand:

```
char min[20], max[20], input[20] ;
printf("Enter word: ");
scanf("%s", &input);
min = input; max = input;
```

Comment: You should drop the `&`, or use `fgets`.  And loop through to copy arrays.

Comment: As @squiguy says, plus in C you copy strings with `strcpy`.  You can easily look that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char min[20], max[20], input[20] ;
printf("Enter word: ");
scanf("%s", input);
strcpy(min, input);
strcpy(max, input);
```

This is how you do it. Note that I have removed  the `&` in the `scanf` also.

`scanf` is not a good function to use - http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

`#include <string.h>` to get the declarations for `strcpy`.

Comment: Thanks, I've used this function before but it slipped my mind. Especially since I'm currently working on various projects in C, Java and Python.  Also, this is for an intro C course where the instructor encourages us to use scanf for simplicity but thanks for showing me issues with it for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to copy input into `max` and `min` array. So code should be

```
char min[20], max[20], input[20] ;
printf("Enter word: ");
scanf("%s", input);
strcpy(min,input);
strcpy(max,input);
```

Answer (score 1):

`memcpy` is your friend:

```
char min[20], max[20], input[20];
memset(min,'d',19);
min[19] = 0;
memcpy(min,max,20);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to copy the string.

```
strncpy(input, min, sizeof(min)-1);
strncpy(input, max, sizeof(max)-1);
//to be careful
min[sizeof(min)-1] = '\0';
max[sizeof(max)-1] = '\0';
```